# Animate grass with CoreAnimation (on the iPhone)

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

how could I animate blades of grass, which are waving in the wind?
I haven't found any suitable CoreAnimation combinations.

Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for, but you could do a port of [this GPU Gems code](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch07.html) over to Quartz 2D.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting technique. I'll try to simplify it for CoreAnimation.